# Decrease priority of posts with multiple flags in 10K tools

Tags: feature-request, flags, 10k-tools

When you view flagged posts on the 10K tools page, it appears that the 50 items are selected at random. As the result, I see answers with eight "not an answer" flags, along with answers that have only one such flag. This may be suboptimal: the more identical flags an item has, the smaller is the value that I could add by seconding the existing flagger's opinion.

I think that it would be better to add weights to the flagged items for the purpose of selecting them for the 10K review: the more flags an item has, the fewer times it should make it to someone's review queue. It may also make sense to drop answers with 4+ identical flags from the 10K queue: these are nearly certainly the "mee too" garbage, so you can just let them sit before the moderators get to it, without asking for additional confirmation of what's already obvious.

Comment: The flag weight of the flaggers might also usefully be taken into account for this. A flag from an 800 FW user perhaps doesn't need to be reviewed by a 10ker, but can go straight to the moderators.