# 10k tools flagged posts - "50 more" link gets same posts

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools

At the bottom of the [10K tools flags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged), there is this text:

> Showing 50 random posts; get [50 more](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged)

When I click on the "50 more" link, the same 50 posts are always shown. (Currently there are 130+ flags).

Am I missing something?

---

Side note:

The quoted text above implies that the posts are shown in a random order, but in reality they seem to be shown in order of the number of flags on the post. Perhaps this is part of the problem.

I did check the [10k-tools] tag on meta - most posts indicate the items are shown in random order.

The following post is a feature request to show posts in a weighted order, but there is not a [status-complete] tag on it: [Decrease priority of posts with multiple flags in 10K tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169460/decrease-priority-of-posts-with-multiple-flags-in-10k-tools)

Comment: Have you flagged any of the items on the first 50 shown?   If you didn't review them by flagging, etc then it is possible you will be shown the same 50 items.  I agree that it seems like the posts are now being shown by number of flags, so possibly removing the _random_ from the note is needed.

Comment: @bluefeet - I have the option for showing posts that I've already flagged turned off. That means I probably am seeing 50 posts that I have not flagged. So what you are saying is that I can't look at the remaining 80+ flags until I flag the ones on the first page? Seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue and it's annoying that I can't look at the remainder of the 300 flags that I haven't handled yet (currently about 25 more are in review). Here too, flags that I have handled are hidden and it does look like the posts are ordered by amount of votes on them.

Comment: I agree it's very annoying. I wish at least there was a "skip" button so that I can get rid of some of the items from my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is no more.

The recent changes to the 10K flags tool mean that all flags are accessible - paging has been added. Now it makes perfect sense to display flags with most votes at the top - no need for the random order.

For me, the issue is sorted out in a very good way.